# Make tag heading bigger than Topic and other elements on the page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

The tag SQL is a major tag, and it should be in the largest heading available or some nice CSS magic. It should exist such that when the eyes see it, immediately you know you are on SQL, and you are looking at this tag. Within it are topics, for example, CASE is a topic.

But for some reason the headings look awful. The word CASE is larger than the word SQL. It should be quite the opposite; it should come in the form of a hierarchy, something to this effect:

## SQL

### Case

#### Example 1

#### Example 2

This way when I'm on the page I can clearly see whose in charge. I used SQL as an example, but you can use any tag name, C#, JavaScript, etc.

Here's the look on the UI:

[image]

I propose to make some CSS changes to make this more hierarchical and allow for tags to be more eye catching.

Comment: I'd be more in favor of just making it the same size as the Topic header; `font-size: 24px;`

Comment: @TylerH - I'd be okay with that too, but making the tag smaller just looks odd.

Comment: *to be more eye catching* -- `<blink>`, `<blink>` ;)